# Does Sequel have anything like ActiveRecord's `merge` method?

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord, sequel

Using [ActiveRecord's `merge` method](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge), if I have a scope on `Author` called `name_like`, I can use that to find books by author name using `Book.joins(:author).merge(Author.name_like("lew"))`

That produces this query (for one version of `name_like`):

```
SELECT "books".* FROM "books" 
INNER JOIN "authors" ON "authors"."id" = "books"."author_id"
WHERE (concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) ILIKE '%lew%')
```

Does [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) have something equivilent to this? I don't see it in [Sequel for ActiveRecord Users](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/active_record_rdoc.html).

Comment: My knowledge of `Sequel` is rather minimalistic, but i think it should be achievable with its `def_dataset_method()` and `dataset_module()`, did you already look into that?

Comment: @wiesion `dataset_module { def name_like(name)...` is how I defined `Author.name_like`, but I don't know how to use it to query for books like `merge` does. I know Sequel likes the concept of sets, so I figure that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything like `merge`.  For a query like that in Sequel, you could do:

```
Book.association_join(:author).
  where(Sequel.join([:first_name, :last_name], ' ').ilike('%lew%'))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for answering my question! The author of Sequel, ladies and gentlemen. :)  (For future reference, the latest Sequel version as of this answer is 4.27.0)

Comment: tbh, i knew about this solution :) but given your question, i thought you want to be able to use something like `.where(Author.name_like('%lew')` instead of doing `Sequel.join`, thus i asked if you have looked into `dataset`.

Comment: @wiesion Yes, I would prefer to be able to re-use the "scope" on `Author`. If you see a way, please add an answer.